# Rest API resources: composed for post but separate to get is ok?

Tags: api, rest

I'm creating a set of RESTful API and I have this question: I have a resource that has some images attached and I'm creating my resources like this:
POST to /resource: create the object and save the images to the server.
GET to /resource returns the object but no the images, GET to /images returns the images.
My question is: is this compliant with REST or should I either make the resources completely separate or completely unified?
I choose this solution because when posting I for sure send the images, but I may need them or not when doing a get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this compliant with REST

It's fine - for instance, if you look at the way that [Atom Publishing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) works, you'll see that when you [post a media to a collection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023#section-9.6), two resources are created (the Media Resource and the Media Link Entry).

However, fine here means you are making tradeoffs.  In particular, [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) is more challenging when you a POST to one resource may change the representation of a different resource.

HTTP caching semantics are optimized for the common case, which is that a given request changes only the target resource; no spooky action at a distance.

That doesn't mean that this is the Right Way, but rather that you should understand that this is the way that HTTP makes easy, and in other cases you need to pay attention to the details.

Answer (score 1):

`POST` can basically mean anything, and unlike `PUT` and `GET` (for which there is a bit more of a direct relation), `POST` is allowed to result in all kinds of side-effects, including the creation of 0 or more resources.

`POST` is basically the 'anything goes' method.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please link me with some references to go deeper into the subject?

Comment: Usually the references I rely the most on is the standards. Read the HTTP specification and read the REST dissertation.